# Out of memory in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I m trying to index some data in ES and I m receiving out of memory exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.util.BufferRecycler.balloc(BufferRecycler.java:155)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.util.BufferRecycler.allocByteBuffer(BufferRecycler.java:96)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.util.BufferRecycler.allocByteBuffer(BufferRecycler.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.io.IOContext.allocWriteEncodingBuffer(IOContext.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.<init>(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:123)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonFactory._createUTF8Generator(JsonFactory.java:1284)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createGenerator(JsonFactory.java:1016)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContent.createGenerator(JsonXContent.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.<init>(XContentBuilder.java:96)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.builder(XContentBuilder.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContent.contentBuilder(JsonXContent.java:38)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.contentBuilder(XContentFactory.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.jsonBuilder(XContentFactory.java:49)
    at EsController.importProductEs(EsController.java:60)
    at Parser.fromCsvToJson(Parser.java:120)
    at CsvToJsonParser.parseProductFeeds(CsvToJsonParser.java:43)
    at MainParser.main(MainParser.java:49)
```

This is how I instantiate the ES client:

```
System.out.println("Elastic search client is instantiated");
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch_brew").build();
client = new TransportClient(settings);
String hostname = "localhost";
int port = 9300; 
((TransportClient) client).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(hostname, port));     
bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
```

and then I run the bulk request:

```
// for each product in the list, we need to include the fields in the bulk request 
for(HashMap<String, String> productfields : products)
        try {
            bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex(index,type,productfields.get("Product_Id"))
                    .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                                .startObject()
                                    .field("Name",productfields.get("Name") )
                                    .field("Quantity",productfields.get("Quantity"))
                                    .field("Make", productfields.get("Make"))
                                    .field("Price", productfields.get("Price"))
                                .endObject()
                              )
                    );                  

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//execute the bulk request
BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
    // process failures by iterating through each bulk response item
}
```

I am trying to index products from various shops. Each shop is a different index. When I reach the 6th shop containing around 60000 products I get the above exception. I split the bulk request in chunks of 10000, trying to avoid the out of memory problems.
I can't understand where exactly is the bottleneck. Would it help if i somehow flush the bulk request or restart the client??
I ve seen similar posts but non works for me.

EDIT

When I m instantiting a new client every time I process a new bulk request, then I don't get the out of memory exception. But instantiating a new client each time doesnt seem right..

Thank you

Comment: What do the imported data look like?

Comment: You just probably have two much products processed at once, given that this error is happening on client side, not on actual ES node.

Comment: @9000 - {"Name":"Wireless Shape Mouse", "Quantity":"100", "Make":"Sony","Price":"23.73"}. This is a line of a product.

Comment: @Bax, I m processing 10.000 at each request, I ll try to reduce it down to 5000.

Comment: Or try to increase the client memory via the -Xmx VM option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what was wrong.

Every new bulk request was adding up to the previous one and eventually it was leading to out of memory.

So now before I start a new bulk request I run the 
`bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();` 
which flushes the previous request.

Thank you guys for your comments